# Elasticsearch historical data handling

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ES with Kibana data tables and want to do some basic computation on the past 7 days of data which would be of around 30-40GB.

I was planning to use Hbase with ES so that it could extract historical data from it but is it possible to store the data in ES itself and then kibana can search over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ES will store the data in the nodes of the ES Cluster and the Kibana will read/render the information in Graphic on query to ES.

Comment: How do you decide storage in the node? Is it configurable?Or does it use RAM of that node?

Comment: I hope you are new baby to ES and I would recommend you to see this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html ; This will help you in understanding ES Cluster, Node and Shards;  The data were stored in ES node and it will also get replicated in to other nodes in the cluster so any loss of one node in cluster will not have much impact to the data and bring new node to the cluster will sync the data back; All the data will be indexed for fast retrieval and search. I hope this answers to your question.